# JobTask for file monitor in a folder

Tags: c#, windows-services, soa

I am working on C#.Net Windows Service Application which will send a pdf file to a printer.  Pdf files are received from a third party fax service. As soon as fax drops the pdf files, we 
need to take a print out.

How to achieve by tracking the recent pdf file and sending them to the printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to monitor the folder.

```
public void Main()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = @"C:\MyPath";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;    
    watcher.Filter = "*.pdf";

    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
}

private static void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks dave, let me try this !!

Comment: How to test this syntax. Because, I have a folder with 3 pdf files. I just copied a new file in the same folder. debugged and used watch analyer to track the recent file. But couldnt help

Comment: @goofyui check my edits. You need to capture the event. There are 4 - `created`, `changed`, `deleted`, `renamed`. If you click the link to MSDN it shows this.

Comment: Thanks Dave, i am checking the msdn. But i need the created event should invoke as soon as watcher detected a new file

Comment: I also played with FileSystemWatcher, but be aware that it is quite unreliable when it gets a lot of changes. You copy over a 100 files at once and FSW stops working, but no error messages, nothing, only no notification. Some said to set InterBufferSize to another value but it wasn't helping.

Comment: @Biri very interesting. I don't have much experience with it but have never had an issue. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @DaveZych: it comes only under high pressure. :-) If you have only let's say one file change per second, it can handle it.

Comment: I am testing this piece of code by changing the files and adding new files. OnCreated event is not invoking. Also in my case, i expect around 100 files to  the folder

Comment: Can you provide your code example? How do you use the above code snippet? Is a command line application, a service, a winforms application, or ...?